# Can't change fragment text view from a method

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I'm trying this simple method to change a fragment text view but the app crashes every time I try to open the activity of the fragment with this fragment code

```
public class FragmentContrat extends Fragment {
    public FragmentContrat() {}

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contrat_fragment, container, false);
        update();
        return view;

    }

    public void update() {
        TextView textView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.souscripteur_txt);
        textView.setText("milan");
    }
```

however it works fine and the TextView change when I put the same code in onCreateView like this :

```
public class FragmentContrat extends Fragment {




    public FragmentContrat() {}


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contrat_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.souscripteur_txt);
        textView.setText("milan");
        return view;

    }
```

the activity code :

```
public class DetailsContrat extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout details_tab;
    AppBarLayout details_bar;
    ViewPager details_pager;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_contrat);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String client_id = i.getStringExtra("client_id");
        details_tab=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.details_tab);
        details_bar=(AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.details_bar);
        details_pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.details_pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        FragmentContrat fragmentContrat = new FragmentContrat();
        FragmentVehicule fragmentVehicule = new FragmentVehicule();
        FragmentGaranties fragmentGaranties = new FragmentGaranties();



 adapter.AddFragment(fragmentContrat,"MON CONTRAT");
        adapter.AddFragment(fragmentVehicule,"MA VOITURE");
        adapter.AddFragment(fragmentGaranties,"MES GARANTIES");
        details_pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        details_tab.setupWithViewPager(details_pager);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreateView` you are creating and the fragment's view. So if you call `getView()`, to get the fragment view you will get null, because you haven't yet returned the just created view.

You can:

1. Use the newly-created view similarly to what @Sanjaysinh's is recommending
2. Avoid setting your text in `onCreateView` and set it in `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)`, that is called after the view has been created ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated()))

Comment: onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) ... where exactly ? example please .

Comment: You have to override the `onViewCreated` method like you did for `onCreateView`.
`@Override void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) { }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass your view in update method

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contrat_fragment, container, false);
    update(view);
    return view;

}

public void update(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.souscripteur_txt);
    textView.setText("milan");
}
```